# why is data.fu implementing HyperLogLog as an accumulator and not as algebraic?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig, cardinality, hyperloglog

data.fu has a nice implementation of HyperLogLog for estimating cardinality [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-datafu/blob/master/datafu-pig/src/main/java/datafu/pig/stats/HyperLogLogPlusPlus.java)

However, it's implemented as `Accumulator` which means it will run only at the reducer and not in the combiner (but it will never load the entire set into memory as in normal `EvalFunc`). Why couldn't data.fu implement it as `Algebraic` - and fill the registers at every combiner, then merge and reduce the result? 
Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as because questions of 'why' software is working as it does are not on topic here. The question might be on-topic for programming-SE but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in 1.3.0, and now it does use `Algebraic`. 
see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DATAFU-91

See details of how this improves a task from 10 minutes to 2 minutes: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oVYSCh22kufgQ49pgsuboKOMxDgz8N5yBtRpxuo69Lk/edit#gid=0